# Google Analytics 4 Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, react-ga

I am saving events using ReactGA [react-ga4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga4) in google analytics.
The method used to save the event is:

```
ReactGA.event({
   category: 'my event category',
   action: 'Event Action'
   label: 'my event label'
})
```

in realtime I am able to see the event being saved.
The name of the event was the action which was set by me and if I click on that I can see **event_label** and **event_category** in which the values which were passed by me are displayed.
but in reports I am not able to see event_label and event_category so that I can group my events accordingly
like for a particular action these were the labels passed as shown in real time.

I have tried creating Custom Dimension in Admin in which I have created two metrics which are Event Label and Event Category and their value as event_label and event_category and then in explore I am selecting those metrics but I am not seeing any values.

Also I have tried setting a dimension using ReactGA.set({ user_name: 'abc' }) but I am not able to find that too.

Thanks